# React: how to get item width from map function

Tags: dictionary, reactjs

I'm newbie to react, I have no idea how to get the width of each item from the React map function. It just return an react element without js functions.

for example:

```
this.props.children.map((child, index) => {
    console.log(child.clientWidth);
})
```

plz advise.
thx.

Answer (score 2):

Use `return`

```
this.props.children.map((child, index) => {
    console.log(child.clientWidth);
    return child.clientWidth
})
```

Comment: sorry, you have misunderstood my meaning, what I mean is I can't use "clientWidth" or other js functions, the "child" actually is an React Element, it  doesn't provide those functions.

I suppose I need to put the js code to the react Lifecycle like "componentDidMount", but I am using async request in my project, the result return empty.